# integrating cocos2d-x with gaf in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

i'm using cocos2d-x 3.7 on windows, visual studio 2013 and GAF_VERSION 5.0.
i'v downloaded "Cocos2dxGAFPlayer" and copied it into cocos2d/external, after that i added the gafplayer project to my cocos2dx project solution. i'm not sure but i think i have configured it properly as its running while it has this code in "HelloWorld::init()" :

```
auto animation = GAFAsset::createWithBundle("anim1.zip", "anim1/anim1.gaf", nullptr);
object = animation->createObjectAndRun(true);
object->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_MIDDLE);
object->setPosition(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize() / 2);
this->addChild(object,1);
```

but by using this only the png file, containing parts of animation is shown( i have attached the file i mean).

when i use the zip file generated by gap in the GAFTest project by only replacing the recourse (not the source code) it works fine.

i've searched the net for a solution, and a correct way to integrate cocos2d-x and gaf. but i couldn't find a way.
please guide me.
is there any tutorial about how to integrate cocos2d-x with gaf on visual studio so i make sure i'm doing the configuration right?
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member of GAFmedia forum suggested something which solved the problem : http://gafmedia.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=447

> > > Postby Dmitry Bushtets » October 7th, 2015, 7:36 am
>
> I have one idea. Have you method call to    CODE: SELECT ALL
>
> ```
> cocos2d::Director::setContentScaleFactor
> ```
>
> in the code? (it can be in AppDelegate.cpp)    If yes - try to remove
>   this call (set content scale factor to 1) and check result.    Or
>   convert swf to gaf with CSF 1 and 2 (and 3, 4 maybe :) ). You can find
>   this option in GAF Converter. [Texture Atlas -> Scale Settings ->
>   Advanced]